# Consider the universal relation R = {A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J}. What is the key for R? Decompose R into 2NF and then 3NF relations

Tags: database

Consider the universal relation R = {A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J} and the set of
functional dependencies F = { {A, B}→{C}, {A}→{D, E}, {B}→{F}, {F}→{G,
H}, {D}→{I, J} }. What is the key for R? Decompose R into 2NF and then
3NF relations.

I tried every solution given on internet but still not able to understand the answer even my instructor is not answering me satisfactorily. Can someone please explain me this?

Yes this was asked in homework but it has already been marked wrong and i just want to learn this concept. Thank you.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about relational database theory, not an actual programming problem.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth .. I think stackoverflow is just not about programming problems ..

Comment: What algorithm does your textbook use to determine all possible candidate keys?

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall'.. Instructor did not say anything about candidate keys in his answer :(

Comment: What algorithm does your textbook use to determine the key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a 6 step process that will lead you to the answer but in many cases the key is to figure out which attribute or set of attributes have only out going relations and no incoming. Here except for A,B all other attributes have dependencies on A,B directly or indirectly. Hence A,B is the key for this relation. This is not the perfect answer but will lead you to the goal in most of the cases.
Once you arrive at the key, use that key and check if you can reach all the attributes directly or transitively. If yes then bingo, you have your key. In your case with A,B we can get to all the attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Attribute set closures

```
AB+=CDEFGHIJ
AF+=CDEGHIJ
A+=CDEIJ
A+=CDEIJ
B+=CFGH
```

Candidate keys `{AB,AF}`
Prime attributes `{A,B,F}`
Non-prime attributes `{C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J}`

Comment: Answer posts without explanation are poor answers. [answer] [Help] https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).